# How to fix the blurry Form or UI of Visual Studio 2019 on C++ Project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

The issue of blurry form or UI of VB.Net on Visual Studio 2019 can be solved by adding and configuring the `app.manifest.xml` of the project and adding the `<dpiAware>true</dpiAware>` into it.

However, I tried using the same approach on my C++ project in Visual Studio 2019 but there's no available manifest to add to the project?

Also, setting the `AutoScaleMode` to `Dpi` of the form didn't work.

How do you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `C++ Project` on `Visual Studio 2019` has a different approach when setting the `DPI Awareness` of the UI.

In order to do so, `Right-Click` on the `Project` then open the `Properties` > `Manifest Tool` > `Input and Output` > `DPI Awareness` and select the option `High DPI Aware`, click Apply and OK buttons then run the project and viola.

Answer (score 0):

You could set `No` in `Properties->Manifest Tool->Input and Output->Embed Manifest` to generate manifest file. Then, you will find it in the `Debug/Release` folder of the project. Open it and add the following code. If it already exists and is commented out, you could uncomment it.

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <windowsSettings>
    <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
  </windowsSettings>
</application>
```